# how to return a single object property from a single object, within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Apologies for the confusing wording but i hope the explanation with code below is more clear, basically I have an array of objects such:

```
const employees = [{
  name: 'Dave',
  role: 'IT'
}, {
  name: 'Jenny',
  role: 'Sales'
}, {
  name: 'Joel',
  role: 'Finance'
}]
```

now i want to create a function which finds the role of a person by searching their name, like:

```
const getEmployeeRole = (employeeName, employees) => {}
```

so i would expect:

```
console.log(getEmployeeRole('Joel', employees))
```

to return `'Finance'`.

I know i can use:

```
employees.map(employees => employees.role)
```

to get the roles for all 3 objects, but i want it to specifically churn it out for a single object only.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Just loop the object, check the property, return the role if found?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method:

```js
const employees = [{
  name: 'Dave',
  role: 'IT'
}, {
  name: 'Jenny',
  role: 'Sales'
}, {
  name: 'Joel',
  role: 'Finance'
}];

var person = "Jenny";

// Just filter the array based on an employee's name
console.log(employees.filter(function(emp){
  return emp.name === person;
}));
```